# Object turns permanently invisible when adding visibility keyframes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, keyframes, visibility

I'm trying to keyframe the viewport and render visibility of a simple plane with an image sequence for the texture. The sequence starts at a certain frame so I want to keep it hidden before that so it doesn't show the purple color.

The file was first in 15fps and is now in 60fps so it uses time stretching, if that changes anything.

However, when I add keyframes to the visibility of this plane all keyframes change to invisible.

Here's a gif to demonstrate what's happening:

[image: Here is a gif demonstrating what's happening]

Here is the .blend file, although it's part of a larger project over the 30 MB limit so I had to delete most parts of it. If there is a problem with that I can host the whole file on Google Drive later, but even in this stripped-down version the issue still persists.

[image]

*Using Blender 3.3.1 with Cycles, Windows 10 x64 for anyone concerned*

Comment: unfortunately you didn't include the timeline marker in the gif so we cannot really see what's going on...and maybe adding a blend file might also help...

Comment: @Chris (et al.) Hmm.. the trouble is, when you key an object invisible this way, it also makes  its keyframes invisible in the timeline... is there a switch to flick which gets around this? The keys are there, alright, you can key back visible, you just can't see them if you're in a period of invisibility.

Comment: @RobinBetts: you are right, didn't think about that....but a blend file would help...so at least my second part is true :D

Comment: @Chris .. Not a criticism of your comment :) Just poking around for an answer ...

Comment: @RobinBetts: i see your comment as a positive and constructive criticism, which is needed and you are right - so i have absolutely no problem with that and i hope you keep doing this in the future! i just can learn from you!

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the inconvenience, I just added both the timeline to the gif and the .blend file with the issue

Comment: Yes the strange thing is that the keyframes become invisible as soon as the object is invisible, even though you still have it selected in the Outliner, it's not logical to me

Comment: @EverythingerTruten I'm quite sure it has something to do with the _Time Stretching_, if I disable it, it seems to work normal to me. But I'm not sure how to counter that.